# Increasing height of a div when hovering it but only with CSS... why?

Tags: html, css, class, hover, height

Maybe are the hours I'm coding, but I can understand why this happens.
Just with CSS and HTML, this code makes a div increase its height by 1 px (I estimate) each time the user hovers it. I don't know why can happen this, this is not the kind of things a CSS hover should do, I has understood... 
Not very important, but curious. Just copy and paste, you will see.
The thing is that all comes when I add the class "barrainferior-cell-selected". This one is the one that produces this unusual conduct...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .barrainferior {
                display:table;
                position:fixed;
                top:auto;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
                left:0;
                width:100%;
                border-bottom:0px solid #FFF;
                background-color:#3C62D5;
            }
            .barrainferior-row {
                display:table-row;
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
                margin:0;
            }
            .barrainferior-cell {
                display:table-cell;
                width:20%;
                height:100%;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border-top:1px solid #444444;
                border-right:1px solid #444444;
                text-align:center;
                cursor:pointer;
                transition:background 0.25s linear;
            }
            .barrainferior-cell:first-child {
                border-left:0px solid #FFF;
            }
            .barrainferior-cell:last-child {
                border-right:0px solid #FFF;
            }
            .barrainferior-cell:hover {
                background-color:#4A87EE;
                border-top:0px solid white;
            }
            .barrainferior-cell-selected {
                background-color:#4A87EE;
                border-top:none;
            }
            .barrainferior-iconowrapper {
                display:table;
            }
            .barrainferior-icono {
                display:table-cell;
                height:19px;
                width:auto;
                padding-top:3px;
                padding-bottom:3px;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            .sinbordederecho {
            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <div class="barrainferior">
                <div class="barrainferior-row">
                    <div class="barrainferior-cell barrainferior-cell-selected" id="icono-home">
                        <div class="barrainferior-cell-iconowrapper">
                            <img class="barrainferior-icono" src="img/icons/home-white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="barrainferior-cell" id="icono-document">
                        <div class="barrainferior-cell-iconowrapper">
                            <img class="barrainferior-icono" src="img/icons/document-white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="barrainferior-cell" id="icono-git">
                        <div class="barrainferior-cell-iconowrapper">
                            <img class="barrainferior-icono" src="img/icons/social-github-white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="barrainferior-cell" id="icono-world">
                        <div class="barrainferior-cell-iconowrapper">
                            <img class="barrainferior-icono" src="img/icons/ios7-world-outline-white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="barrainferior-cell sinbordederecho" id="icono-person">
                        <div class="barrainferior-cell-iconowrapper">
                            <img class="barrainferior-icono" src="img/icons/person-white.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the beautiness of the code, but I couldn't understand what was the StackOverflow code editor demanding... Sorry...

Comment: How about you creating a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you for beautifying the code.
Thank you for your attention, LJ_1102.
It seems that the thing was the "height: 100%" attribute of the "barrainferior-cell" that was making "win" all the time 1px of height when the hover restablishes. It is done now with "height:auto".
Thank you for the interest!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.barrainferior-cell:hover {
     background-color:#4A87EE;
     border-top:1px solid #444444;
}
```

I think [this](http://jsbin.com/bonupe/2/edit) is want you wanted

Comment: Effectively, that was it. By default, the "height" property's value is "auto", I just did it explicitly. Thank you for the example, Parsi.